# Restrict crawling of region/lang combinations other than the provided ones in robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I want to allow crawling of my website only if the URL starts with accepted region/language combinations which are `us/en`, `gb/en` and `fr/fr`. Other language combinations must be restricted. On the other hand crawler should be able to crawl `/` or `/about`, etc. For example:

```
example.com/us/en/videos  # should be allowed
example.com/de/en/videos  # should be blocked
example.com/users/mark    # should be allowed
```

Again, it should be blocked only if it starts with unaccepted region/language combinations.
What I did so far does not work:

```
Disallow: /*?
Disallow: /*/*/cart/
Disallow: /*/*/checkout/
Disallow: /*/*/
Allow: /*.css?
Allow: /*.js?
Allow: /us/en/
Allow: /gb/en/
Allow: /fr/fr/
```

I tested it with google's online robots.txt tester.

Comment: Assuming you have the `User-agent: *` line then what you've posted works as intended in "Google's online robots.txt tester". If you've missed the user-agent line then the tool reports a stack of errors: "No user-agent specified". (?)

Comment: @MrWhite, yes I added user-agent line. but it does not work as I expect.

Comment: "it does not work as I expect" - and what do you expect? When I said it "works as intended", I mean it satisfies the 3 criteria you've stated. ie. `/us/en/videos` IS allowed, `/de/en/videos` IS blocked and `/users/mark` IS allowed. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite, nope. when i test it at google's tool it blocks them all. and it says that `/*/*/` rule is the reason of blocking.

Comment: Are you including the slash prefix on your input?

Comment: @MrWhite I tried both, with and without slashes. Did it work for you? i use this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en

Comment: Yes, it works for me. (I've posted screenshots in my answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the `User-agent: *` directive on the first line then what you've posted appears to work as intended in "[Google's online robots.txt tester](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en)". In that it satisfies the 3 (or more) criteria you've stated:

1. `example.com/us/en/videos` IS **allowed**
2. `example.com/de/en/videos` IS BLOCKED
3. `example.com/users/mark` IS **allowed**
4. `example.com/` IS **allowed**
5. `example.com/about` IS **allowed**
6. `example.com/us/en/` (with or without the trailing slash) IS **allowed**
7. `example.com/gb/en/` (with or without the trailing slash) IS **allowed**
8. `example.com/fr/fr/` (with or without the trailing slash) IS **allowed**

As per the screenshots below...

> ## 1. example.com/us/en/videos

[image: example.com/us/en/videos]

> ## 2. example.com/de/en/videos

[image: example.com/de/en/videos]

> ## 3. example.com/users/mark

[image: example.com/users/mark]

> ## 4. example.com/

[image: example.com/]

> ## 5. example.com/about

[image: example.com/about]

Comment: ok, now I see what is my mistake. I tested it with `https://sites.google.com/site/ezizdurdy/`. sorry to waste your time. :/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the `?` character in a robots.txt file before. Are you sure you don't mean to use `$` instead, which denotes the end of the string?

Furthermore, your file needs to specify user-agent at the top for which bots to affect. Here's a revised file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?
Disallow: /*/*/cart/
Disallow: /*/*/checkout/
Disallow: /*/*/
Allow: /*.css$
Allow: /*.js$
Allow: /us/en/
Allow: /gb/en/
Allow: /fr/fr/
```

This is closer to what you want. To affect only Googlebot, change `User-agent: *` to `User-agent: Googlebot`.

But it does seem like different robots.txt checking tools read it differently. [Google's tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool) blocks `/us/en/cart/`, for instance, while [technicalseo's tool](https://technicalseo.com/tools/robots-txt/) and [seobook.com's tool](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/analyzer/) both allow the same URL. Not sure how to reconcile that one.

Comment: The `?` is just a literal `?` - so this would match URLs that contain a query string (in the case of CSS and JS files, this might be used to indicate version/cache busting). "technicalseo's tool" appears to _disallow_ that URL when I tried, not "allow" it? Although "seobook.com's tool" does appear to (incorrectly) allow it. (?)

Comment: "seobook.com's tool" appears to just process every directive and whatever end result spits out is what it goes with - which (AFAIK) is not how any real crawler behaves.